# Do the rules in the "Open the first time a faction is eliminated" packet apply retroactively?

Tags: risk-legacy

Contains spoilers for the packet in question:

> In Risk Legacy, a faction was eliminated and I opened the appropriate envelope, inside which were blue comeback power stickers. My question is: does that very first eliminated faction get one of the stickers, or will it have to wait until next time since these new rules only came into existence after it was eliminated?

Answer (score 1):

The card included in the packet covers what to do:

> The card in question reads 
>  "The player controlling the eliminated faction chooses a comeback power and places it on to the blue slot on his faction card. From now on, whenever a faction with an empty blue slot is knocked out or eliminated, the controlling player chooses a comeback power and places it on to the blue slot on his faction card." These two statements are independent of each other, so the first faction to be eliminated does add a comeback power to their card.